# Predicate in prolog which is true if A is smaller or equal to B

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I want to write a predicate `test(A,B)` in prolog which is true if A is smaller or equal to B.

Examples for a query (should return true):

```
test(s(s(0)), s(s(s(0)))).
test(s(s(s(0))), s(s(s(0)))).
```

This is the code which I've written so far:

```
test(0,0).
test(0, s(B)) :- nat(B).
test(s(A),s(B)) :- test(A,B).
```

but it does not work.

Comment: What is the definition of `nat/1` ??

Comment: nat(B) is for natural numbers

Comment: Yes but what is the definition you wrote about `nat/1` ?? cause the problem might be there...

Comment: *but it does not work*. Please be specific. What is the error or failure case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you use natural numbers as '0 is 0' and 's(A) is A+1'. Then you can write it like this:

```
test(0,_).                            % everything is bigger or equal to 0.
test(s(A),s(B)) :- test(A,B).         % s(A) <= s(B) when A <= B
```

We are going down with A and B until:
1) A becomes 0 - that means A <= B, true is returned
2) B becomes 0 and A not - it means B > A, false is returned.